# Movable Type archive pages – show all entries in a top-level category or its subcategories

Tags: movabletype

I have a MT blog. Originally it had a bunch of categories:

- Apple
- Pear
- Banana
- Grape

We've expanded our content and created some parent categories:

- Animal

  - Dog
  - Cat
  - Duck
- Vegetable

  - Apple
  - Pear
  - Banana
  - Grape
- Mineral

  - Iron
  - Copper
  - Silver

All of the newly-written Entries have been added to both the top-level category and whatever sub-categories are appropriate. However, the old entries are only tagged with the original category they belonged to, which is now a subcategory. Therefore, the old entries do not appear in the category index pages for top-level categories (Animal/, Vegetable/, or Mineral/).

We don't want to have to manually edit every single old entry to add the correct top-level category. Is there a way to tell the Category Archive / Index page to include any entry that either in the TLC or one of its subcategories, without duplicating the entries? In other words, "Mineral" should list unique entries that are in Mineral, Iron, Copper, or Silver.

Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are in an 'entry listing' (category archive) context/template it should be enough to add:

```
include_subcategories="1"
```

to your 'mt:Entries' loop, just like on this sample:

```
<mt:Entries include_subcategories="1">
...
</mt:Entries>
```

You may have to add at least one entry directly to the parent / top-level category to get the page to generate.

Comment: Awesome, this worked! Thanks both for your answers. :)

Comment: FYI – At first this seemed to only work with "Animals", where I had explicitly added one entry directly to the "Animals" top level category. The page for "Minerals", which didn't directly have any entries assigned to it, still wasn't being generated. I had to explicitly add a single entry directly to the "Minerals" TLC to get MT to generate the page. The page, once generated, included all the expected subcategory entries.

Comment: @MihaiBocsaru, I'm going to edit your answer to include this finding.

Comment: @ElBel Ah, that’s a good point. I believe Movable Type wouldn’t even parse the template for a category with no entries, so the template code change wouldn’t matter. I’ll file a feature request for this.

Comment: The trick that I'm using to force empty categories to generate a page is to create an entry called 'Trick' and tag it like '@trick'. Then, inside the mt:Entries loop I'm filtering out that entry using something like: <mt:Entries tag="NOT @trick">...</mt:Entries>.

Answer (score 3):

**Update:**
As Mihai pointed out, you actually can just use the `include_subcategories="1"` modifier to do this. Just tested and verified, and no plugins required. Save my solution for a more complicated module that needs to pull entries from other categories entirely. ;-)

---

This is difficult by default because Movable Type’s entry listing templates automatically inherit a specific context from which to pull entries or pages.

One possible solution is using the [Out Of Context](https://plugins.movabletype.org/outofcontext/index.html) plugin, which gives you a new `OutOfContext` block tag that you can use to break out of the context that is currently limiting you to pulling entries from a specific category.

Your code might look something like:

```
<mt:CategoryLabel setvar="cat_label">

<mt:OutOfContext>
  <mt:Entries category="$cat_label" include_subcategories="1" lastn="0">
    <!-- entry code here -->
  </mt:Entries>
</mt:OutOfContext>
```

I didn’t test this particular example, so please let me know if you try it!